# Android ListActivity suddenly broke, can't find android.R.id.list even though its there

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-listview, listactivity

I realize that many of these questions floats around out there but I never found anyone with my exact problem.

As far as I can see, I'm doing it right, and it worked yesterday. Today I was working on other parts of my application and wanted to test it. Now I get this obnoxious error that it can't find the list with the id android.R.id.list, but again, it seems to be there.

Could any changes to other parts of the app have caused this, and in that case, how?
Can anybody see the error, cause I sure can't.

I'm sorta desperate here since it's a school project and it's due soon.
Thanks everybody, beforehand, for your time!

(in MainActivity.java)

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}
```

(activity_main.xml)

```
<ListView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

</ListView>
```

`LOGCAT` as requested:

```
01-13 19:00:48.852: W/dalvikvm(25254): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40e6da08)
01-13 19:00:48.857: E/AndroidRuntime(25254): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-13 19:00:48.857: E/AndroidRuntime(25254): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{org.ajhansen.meetme/org.ajhansen.meetme.MainActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'
01-13 19:00:48.857: E/AndroidRuntime(25254):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2463)
01-13 19:00:48.857: E/AndroidRuntime(25254):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2520)
01-13 19:00:48.857: E/AndroidRuntime(25254):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:162)
01-13 19:00:48.857: E/AndroidRuntime(25254):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1366)
01-13 19:00:48.857: E/AndroidRuntime(25254):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-13 19:00:48.857: E/AndroidRuntime(25254):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
01-13 19:00:48.857: E/AndroidRuntime(25254):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5751)
01-13 19:00:48.857: E/AndroidRuntime(25254):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-13 19:00:48.857: E/AndroidRuntime(25254):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-13 19:00:48.857: E/AndroidRuntime(25254):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1083)
01-13 19:00:48.857: E/AndroidRuntime(25254):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:850)
01-13 19:00:48.857: E/AndroidRuntime(25254):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-13 19:00:48.857: E/AndroidRuntime(25254): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'
01-13 19:00:48.857: E/AndroidRuntime(25254):    at android.app.ListActivity.onContentChanged(ListActivity.java:243)
01-13 19:00:48.857: E/AndroidRuntime(25254):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:345)
01-13 19:00:48.857: E/AndroidRuntime(25254):    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1929)
01-13 19:00:48.857: E/AndroidRuntime(25254):    at org.ajhansen.meetme.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:72)
01-13 19:00:48.857: E/AndroidRuntime(25254):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5165)
01-13 19:00:48.857: E/AndroidRuntime(25254):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1103)
01-13 19:00:48.857: E/AndroidRuntime(25254):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2419)
01-13 19:00:48.857: E/AndroidRuntime(25254):
```

... 11 more

Comment: Can you post the actual error in logcat? and which Activity class do you extends

Comment: Try Project (On the top) > Clean > Select Project

Comment: Delete gen&bin folders.

Comment: I just tried commenting out the ListActivity parts and return it to a basic activity. This made the app run but with the wrong layout

Answer (score 1):

A lot of people get errors with R file not generating properly etc., What I usually try as other's have suggested is the Clean action. If that doesn't work go through all your xml files and fine comb them cause any small error missing < or > can cause the R file to break. If this fails, delete the working project but keep the files on disk, then create a new project from existing code (assuming you're using eclipse) and find the path to the project folder. Make sure you tick copy to workspace and that usually solves my issues.

Comment: I cleaned and now R wont generate :/

Comment: @ajhansen If "refresh" doesn't regenerate R, check the console/error tab for errors building the resources. This would also explain the exception you got it the first place.

Comment: I've been through every single line of XML and no errors. A few warnings, but nothing that made it fail before.

Comment: Try deleting the project from workspace and creating a new project from existing code.

Answer (score 0):

Your posted code does not seem to have any problem. It works fine. However, i was able to reproduce the same error as you got by changing the content of `activity_main.xml` with something different i.e. anything except ListView with `@android:id/list` as its id. Hence i would guess that somehow the correct layout file is not being fetched during `setContentView`. In order to check the content of the layout file, you may try replacing the `onCreate` code with this one,

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    XmlPullParser xpp = getResources().getLayout(R.layout.activity_main);
    int eventType;
    try {
        eventType = xpp.getEventType();
        while (eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
            if (eventType == XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {
                Log.d("DEBUG_TAG", "Start tag " + xpp.getName());
            }
            eventType = xpp.next();
        }
    } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}
```

Replace the "DEBUG_TAG" with your choice of tag to view the output in LogCat. If correct layout is fetched then you should get something similar to following in your LogCat.

> 01-14 00:43:00.671: D/DEBUG_TAG(29931): Start tag ListView

Comment: Well certainly looks promising. Right now I can't get Eclipse to regenerate R.java and can't run anything :(

Any ideas?

Comment: i guess, search by tag [r.java-file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/r.java-file?sort=frequent&pageSize=15) would be helpful to you. :)

Answer (score -1):

Try

```
<ListView 
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

Cal the list view like

```
ListView mlist = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
```

Then clean your project and check.

Comment: This will certainly break `ListActivity`

Comment: If someone uses Listview in layout ,then no need to extend listactivity or create dinamic listview. just use my solution then let me know.

Comment: Yeah, that kinda goes straight against any documentation I read, thanks though for your suggestion.